# Arranging coordinates into clockwise order

Tags: c++, objective-c, c, math, screen-scraping

I have 9 screen coordinates, each representing one of 9 positions. From the top right, I want that position to start as the 1st position, and the following clockwise coordinates to represent the 2nd, 3rd, 4th and so on, up until the 9th, which would be the top left coordinate.

Would anybody here be able to come up with some sort of mathematical means of determining which of the 9 coordinates is in which position? They're all relative to each other, and will always be THAT relative to each other.

Example coordinates could be:

```
(x,y)
X   Y
663 382
543 454
303 454
183 382
418 459
543 209
303 209
653 259
183 259
```

Plotting into an image something like:
[image: Representation of coordinates]

Would anybody have any ideas? I simply want some form of programmatic way of listing these coordinates in clockwise order...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Find the center of the "circle," i.e., the average X and average Y

Shift the X and Y values so all are relative to the new center.

Convert to polar coordinates and sort by angle.

Comment: Sorting by angle around the centroid is a good idea, but if the order is required to be clockwise starting at "top right", a few details remain to be worked out in defining the angle.  Polar theta increases from zero in the x-axis direction and goes counterclockwise

Comment: To be honest, it doesn't need to be starting top right, it only needs to be consistent. So, if for the first time, the point on the top left happens to be the first position, it always needs to be first position of the clockwise cycle. It'd be a preference that the top right is the starting point, but it's technically not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understand you correctly, I would just do something like

newPosition = (originalPosition + # of rotations) mod 8

Where I am assuming that the first position is 0, and that you can only make the things jump clockwise by integer increments (hence the # of rotations)