# Order coordinates around center coordinate - JAVA

Tags: java, algorithm, coordinates

I'm trying to create an algorithm that orders coordinates around one certain point, in this case; the middle point.

I have found: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11352110/arranging-coordinates-into-clockwise-order) post, and I came across this reply:

```html
- Find the center of the "circle," i.e., the average X and average Y
- Shift the X and Y values so all are relative to the new center.
- Convert to polar coordinates and sort by angle.
```

Since I am relatively new to this kind of algorithms I decided to ask it here. The reply written above makes somewhat sense to me, but I have no idea what is meant with that.

**Example:**

Img: [click to open](http://prntscr.com/6tmq8v)

Having the image above, *(2,2)* would be the center (green dot).
If one would draw an 'circle' around that center, and it would go along the **red** squares, it would be ordered like:

(0, 4)-> (2,4) -> (2,3) -> (4,3) -> (3,0) -> (1,1)

**If it would start from the left-top-corner ofcourse.** But you get the point.

If someone could point me into the right-direction and/or give me some pseudo code, i'd greatly appreciate it.

Thanks!

Comment: The post you've quoted tells you everything. What part causes you trouble?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quoted answer gives a very high level description. You don't actually need polar coordinates. Particularly, you don't need the distance of the points to the origin. All you need is the angle between the x-axis and the line that goes from the origin to the respective point.

Based on these angles, you can create a `Comparator`, and then use [Collections#sort](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-java.util.Comparator-) to sort the list of points, passing in this comparator.

There are many degrees of freedom for the details of the implementation. However, here is a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), using some of the methods that I had readily available here from a geometry utilities package that I wrote:

```
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

public class SortPointsByAngle
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Point center = new Point(2,2);
        List<Point> points = new ArrayList<Point>();
        points.add(new Point(0, 4));
        points.add(new Point(2, 4));
        points.add(new Point(2, 3));
        points.add(new Point(4, 3));
        points.add(new Point(3, 0));
        points.add(new Point(1, 1));

        List<Point> copy = new ArrayList<Point>(points);
        Collections.shuffle(copy, new Random(0));

        System.out.println("shuffled : "+stringFor(copy));
        Collections.sort(copy, 
            Collections.reverseOrder(byAngleComparator(center)));
        System.out.println("sorted   : "+stringFor(copy));
        System.out.println("reference: "+stringFor(points));
    }

    private static String stringFor(List<Point> points)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        boolean first = true;
        for (Point p : points)
        {
            if (!first)
            {
                sb.append(",");
            }
            first = false;
            sb.append("("+p.x+","+p.y+")");
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    /**
     * Creates a comparator that compares points by the angle that the line
     * between the given center and the point has to the x-axis.
     * 
     * @param center The center
     * @return The comparator
     */
    public static Comparator<Point2D> byAngleComparator(
        Point2D center)
    {
        final double centerX = center.getX();
        final double centerY = center.getY();
        return new Comparator<Point2D>()
        {
            @Override
            public int compare(Point2D p0, Point2D p1)
            {
                double angle0 = angleToX(
                    centerX, centerY, p0.getX(), p0.getY());
                double angle1 = angleToX(
                    centerX, centerY, p1.getX(), p1.getY());
                return Double.compare(angle0, angle1);
            }
        };
    }

    /**
     * Computes the angle, in radians, that the line from (x0,y0) to (x1,y1) 
     * has to the x axis
     * 
     * @param x0 The x-coordinate of the start point of the line
     * @param y0 The y-coordinate of the start point of the line
     * @param x1 The x-coordinate of the end point of the line
     * @param y1 The y-coordinate of the end point of the line
     * @return The angle, in radians, that the line has to the x-axis
     */
    private static double angleToX(
        double x0, double y0, double x1, double y1)
    {
        double dx = x1 - x0;
        double dy = y1 - y0;
        double angleRad = Math.atan2(dy, dx); 
        return angleRad;
    }
}
```

The output is

```
shuffled : (3,0),(2,4),(2,3),(1,1),(4,3),(0,4)
sorted   : (0,4),(2,4),(2,3),(4,3),(3,0),(1,1)
reference: (0,4),(2,4),(2,3),(4,3),(3,0),(1,1)
```

Comment: Awesome! I worked around your code and made it fit into mine, and it works like a charm. Do you happen to have any documentation regarding the 'byAngleComperator' ?

Comment: What do you mean by "documentation"? (Beyond the JavaDoc)? It computes two angles and compares them - that's it.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to see your coordinates as vectors and calculate their length from the center point. Having those results you can order them simply by length.

Comment: You mean ordering them by distance to the center point? I'm not entirely following you :P (I'm not native english speaker). Could u enlighten me :)?

Comment: For each red square you can compute it's distance from the center point. Using the euclidean vector length (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_vector#Length). After having computed these values you can sort the vectors by their lengths (distance from the center point)

Comment: I think the *length* is not what he's looking for. It seems like they should be sorted by their *angle*.